# Bigcommerce API - Creating Webhooks - Invalid Header

Tags: php, bigcommerce, webhooks, guzzle

I'm making small steps into this project I am working on. Now creating and registering a webhook. I'm getting the below response:

**400 - Invalid Header**

I have tried the following code:

```
// Send a request to register a web hook
$http2 = new Client('https://api.bigcommerce.com', array(
    'request.options' => array(
        'exceptions' => false,
        'headers' => array(
            'X-Auth-Client' => $client_id,
            'X-Auth-Token'  => $access_token,
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
            'X-Custom-Auth-Header' => $access_token,
        )
    )
));
$request = $http2->post('/'.$store_hash.'/v2/hooks', null, array(
    'scope'         => 'store/order/*',
    'destination'   => 'https://example.com/process_order.php',
    'is_active'     => true
));
$response = $request->send();
$body = $response->getBody(true);
var_dump($body);

echo '<p>Status Code: ' .  $response->getStatusCode() . '</p>';
```

... and

```
// Send a request to register a web hook
$http2 = new Client('https://api.bigcommerce.com', array(
    'request.options' => array(
        'exceptions' => false,
        'headers' => array(
            'X-Auth-Client' => $client_id,
            'X-Auth-Token'  => $access_token,
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        )
    )
));
$request = $http2->post('/'.$store_hash.'/v2/hooks', null, array(
    'scope'         => 'store/order/*',
    'headers'       => array(
        'X-Custom-Auth-Header' => $access_token,
    ),
    'destination'   => 'https://example.com/process_order.php',
    'is_active'     => true
));
$response = $request->send();
$body = $response->getBody(true);
var_dump($body);

echo '<p>Status Code: ' .  $response->getStatusCode() . '</p>';
```

I am working with the documentation here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/webhooks#create-a-hook

However, I can't seem to work out what **{secret_auth_password}** is as well? The documentation doesn't explain this. I am sending the Client ID and Client Header as part of the headers as well.

Still getting Invalid Header as a response.

I am using Guzzle.

Can anyone assist me on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally worked out what I did wrong after numerous attempts.

Answer: send the data in JSON format.

Resolved Code:

```
// Send a request to register a web hook
$http3 = new Client('https://api.bigcommerce.com', array(
    'request.options' => array(
        'exceptions' => false,
        'headers' => array(
            'X-Auth-Client' => $client_id,
            'X-Auth-Token'  => $access_token,
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
            'Accept'        => 'application/json',
        )
    )
));
$request = $http3->post('/'.$store_hash.'/v2/hooks', null, json_encode(array(
    'scope'         => 'store/order/statusUpdated',
    'destination'   => 'https://example.com/process_order.php',
)));
$response = $request->send();
```

Comment: I have use this code in our custom script inside but getting error--- Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Client' not found in